# Checkbox using the variable value as an email address

Tags: php

I am in the process of creating a form that is populated by data extracted from a database. The information is contact details of users in a company. eg Mobile no. and Email address. The thing I trying to do is with the use of checkbox's select which users to send a message to. The form is created in a table that displays checkbox, ID, Surname, Names, Mobile, EMail and department. The checkbox value is = to the ID of the same row's information. How do i display the value in the input field. Here is the code that I have so far.

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']    ?>">
<?php

// setting variables
$db_host = "localhost";
$username = "userN";
$password = "PassW";
$db_name = "DB_name";

//Connect to db
$link = mysql_connect("$db_host","$username","$password");

// check connection
if (!$link) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

// select table in db
$db = mysql_select_db("$db_name");

// check if db selected 
if (!$db) {
    die ('Can\'t use ' . $db_name . mysql_error());
}

// query data
$res = mysql_query('SELECT ID, Surname, Names, Mobile, EMail, Department FROM rars  limit 0, 10');

// check if query is working
if (!$res) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}


// setting table and heading
echo "<table height='50px' width='100%' border='1' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='4' bgcolor='#EEEEEE'>
        <tr align='center'>
        <td width='10'><font color='#222222' size='2'><strong></font></strong></td>
        <td><font color='#222222' size='2'><strong>ID</font></strong></td> 
        <td><font color='#222222' size='2'><strong>Surname</font></strong></td>
        <td><font color='#222222' size='2'><strong>Name</font></strong></td>
    <td><font color='#222222' size='2'><strong>Mobile</font></strong></td>
    <td><font color='#222222' size='2'><strong>EMail</font></strong></td>
    <td><font color='#222222' size='2'><strong>Department</font></strong></td>

      </tr>";

// populating array
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{

 echo "<tr align='center'>";
//populating rest of columns
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='$row[ID]'>" . "</td>";
    echo "<td><font color='#111111' size='2'>" . $row['ID'] . "</font></strong></td>";
    echo "<td><font color='#111111' size='2'>" . $row['Surname'] . "</font></strong>   </td>";
    echo "<td><font color='#111111' size='2'>" . $row['Names'] . "</font></strong></td>";
    echo "<td><font color='#111111' size='2'>" . $row['Mobile'] . "</font></strong></td>";
    echo "<td><font color='#111111' size='2'>" . $row['EMail'] . "</font></strong></td>";
    echo "<td><font color='#111111' size='2'>" . $row['Department'] . "</font></strong></td>";
 echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>"; 

// closing db    
mysql_close($link); 

?>

<br><br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /> <br><br>
<?php
if($_POST['submit'])
{
    if(isset($_POST['checkbox']))
    {
        $emails = $_POST['checkbox'];
        echo "The following email addresses have been selected: <br />";
        foreach($emails as $key => $value)
        {
            echo $value . "<br />";
        }

    }
    else
    {
         echo "no email address selected";
    }
}
?> 

</form>
```

When you select some of the checkbox's and clicking submit no ID's are displayed. 
If you could help it would be most appreciated.
Thanks Danny

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: well this is exactly how you'd do it. what's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I right in thinking you mean the id just isnt being output in the checkbox value?  If so just change the line that looks like this:

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='$row[ID]'>" . "</td>";
```

and change to:

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='".$row['ID']."'></td>";
```

Just please be aware that the functions for mysql you are using in this script are now deprecated.  Improved functions such as mysqli and PDO are now used.

Comment: Close, but you should also put the element name `ID` into quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes the id is not being out putted. I have now tried your suggestion but still no output. The other problem is the mysqli statement somehow don't select the database but that's not an issue at this point. I'M scrapping the db for a more direct connection to the server so it can handle the authentication of the user. This is my change.    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='".$row['ID']."'>" . "</td>";

Comment: I’m running on opensuse 12.3 with a apache2 web server v 2.2.22 php 5.3.17 and mysql 5.5.29. Just to set the environment

Comment: Thank for putting me on the right track I have solved my problem. I needed to change the name to include the $row['ID'.